# Drag finger across, trigger views albatross

Tags: android, android-studio

What method is used on strings in guitar apps that when you drag your finger across the screen, particular strings start to make their sound?
I am developing one and I have tried many different options e.g. OnTouchListener with ACTION_DOWN modified, OnClickListener similarly, Focus etc. 
Could you write some simple code sample that will complete this task? Drag finger randromly across the screen without releasing it and trigger many views?
Any help will be appreciated